# archetype: how to remove the bytes that are prepended by the pack() routine

Tags: smart-contracts, compile, archetype, metadata

I am trying to concatenate two strings and then convert to bytes using pack(). However this prepends some bytes to the front of the result.

```
var str1 : string = "TEST INDEX #";
var str2 = concat(str1, nat_to_string(index));
var str3 = pack(str2);
```

The result is 0x05010000000d5445535420494e444558202331. It appears 05010000000d is being prepended.

Is there a way to remove those bytes? Or another builtin function that I have missed?

I tried using slice to remove them (an idea from another post that had the same issue with smartpy).

```
var byt2 = slice(str3, 0, 6);
```

However, when adding the result from slice into a *var* of type *map<string, bytes>* I get the following error:

Archetype compiler: File "indexer.arl", line 62, characters 1154-1158: Incompatible types: found 'option' but expected 'bytes'

I'm unsure where my vars are getting converted to option.

From what i understand, the prepended bytes contain length information so the slice method might not be very scalable.

I would like to store the result in the token_metadata storage so the prepended bytes are not playing nicely with BCD or tzkt.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `slice` builtin returns an option as mentioned [here](https://archetype-lang.org/docs/reference/expressions/builtins/#slice(s%20:%20T,%20o%20:%20nat,%20l%20:%20nat)).

Hence you need to extract the value from the option, with `?=` assignment instruction for example:

```
var byt2 ?= slice(str3, 0, 6) : "INVALID_STR";
```

You should use VScode to edit archetype because the extension will show you the error in place.

Unfortunately the `pack` builtin does not use hex encoding or byte encoding that could be read by BCD or tzkt for example; hence you can't really use it for metadata.

If you want hex encoding for example, you can implement it like this:

```
function string_to_hex(s : string) : string {
  const hex : map<string, string> = [
    (" ","20"); ("!","21"); ("\"","22");("#","23"); ("$","24"); ("%","25"); ("&","26"); ("'","27");
    ("(","28"); (")","29"); ("*","2A"); ("+","2B"); (",","2C"); ("-","2D"); (".","2E"); ("/","2F");
    ("0","30"); ("1","31"); ("2","32"); ("3","33"); ("4","34"); ("5","35"); ("6","36"); ("7","37");
    ("8","38"); ("9","39"); (":","3A"); (";","3B"); ("<","3C"); ("=","3D"); (">","3E"); ("?","3F");
    ("@","40"); ("A","41"); ("B","42"); ("C","43"); ("D","44"); ("E","45"); ("F","46"); ("G","47");
    ("H","48"); ("I","49"); ("J","4A"); ("K","4B"); ("L","4C"); ("M","4D"); ("N","4E"); ("O","4F");
    ("P","50"); ("Q","51"); ("R","52"); ("S","53"); ("T","54"); ("U","55"); ("V","56"); ("W","57");
    ("X","58"); ("Y","59"); ("Z","5A");("[","5B"); ("\\","5C"); ("]","5D"); ("^","5E"); ("_","5F");
    ("`","60"); ("a","61"); ("b","62"); ("c","63"); ("d","64"); ("e","65"); ("f","66"); ("g","67");
    ("h","68"); ("i","69"); ("j","6A"); ("k","6B"); ("l","6C"); ("m","6D"); ("n","6E"); ("o","6F");
    ("p","70"); ("q","71"); ("r","72"); ("s","73"); ("t","74"); ("u","75"); ("v","76"); ("w","77");
    ("x","78"); ("y","79"); ("z","7A"); ("{","7B"); ("|","7C"); ("}","7D"); ("~","7E")
  ];
  var res : list<string> = [];
  iter i to length(s) do
    res.prepend((slice(s, abs(i), 1) ? (hex[the] ? the : "") : ""))
  done;
  return concat(reverse(res))
}
```

if you want `string_to_bytes`, just let us know, we will provide you with the code.

These two builtins are typically something we could add to the archetype builtins.

Comment: Thank you Benoit, this was very helpful. I have installed the vscode extension and it's been helpful when integrating the string_to_hex function above. Thank you for the offer about the code for string_to_bytes, that would be helpful as I would like to convert the string to bytes. Maybe some others here would also find it useful. Thanks again!

Comment: I modified your code to for string_to_bytes, testing just numbers. Seems to work nicely.